# Prevent SQL Injection in JavaScript / Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sql-injection

I am using Node.js to create a Discord bot. Some of my code looks as follows:

```js
var info = {
  userid: message.author.id
}

connection.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = '" + message.author.id + "'", info, function(error) {
  if (error) throw error;
});
```

People have said that the way I put in `message.author.id` is not a secure way. How can I do this? An example?

Answer (score 9):

The best way to is to use prepared statements or queries (link to documentation for NPM `mysql` module: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries)

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = ?";
var inserts = [message.author.id];
sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
```

If prepared statements is not an option (I have no idea why it wouldn't be), a poor man's way to prevent SQL injection is to escape all user-supplied input as described here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#MySQL_Escaping

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared queries;

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = ?";
var inserts = [message.author.id];
sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentantion on how to properly escape any user provided data to prevent SQL injections: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values .
`mysql.escape(userdata)` should be enough.